# How do i find what is increasing the size of my andorid so file

Tags: android, android-ndk

Hey i'm using a native library for my android application and it compiles to an so file of size 2.5 mb. i tried different ways to reduce the size but did not get a solution. i was wondering if i could find out what exactly is causing the size issue by going through the so file is this possible.

Comment: It seems that your library is not stripped. Did you check size for Debug and Release builds, for example the Release size of my native library is more smaller then Debug: 2,4M vs 8,1M.

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk the so file right now does  not have any debug symbols. i made sure to turn them off but the final size is 2.3 mb

Answer (score 0):

When you are using AndroidStudio you can just open the apk in it. It will you the content of it and what size the diffrent components have.

Comment: It seems that size already known -  2.5 mb, isn't it?

Comment: i'm not aiming for the size of the so file by i want to know what components in the so file has created this size. was it the code or linking some libs etc

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze APK with `APK Analyzer` by drag APK file into Android Studio. It will show detail of classes and resources size.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Comment: The question was about native library not Java code.

Comment: not what i'm looking for i need to know the specifics of the so file it self

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/bloaty can show you a breakdown of where the space is being spent. It can also diff two binaries to show you the changes, which is really helpful when trying to figure out what effect any flags you tweak might be having.